# preg_match_all alpha+accented character, but not numeric

Tags: php

I would like to use [php](/questions/tagged/php)'s `preg_match` to capture substrings which comprise:

- A-Z, a-z, all accented chars
- space
- hyphen

It must not capture strings with anything else in them, including numeric chars.

This example is close but also catches strings containing numeric chars:

```
preg_match("/([\p{L} -]+)/u", $string)
```

A similar question already had an answer (the one above) but it doesn't work...

Comment: [I don't see what the problem is? This works fine in PCRE.](http://regex101.com/r/cA0yZ3)

Comment: Anchors (^ and $) are missing: `/^([\p{L} -]+)$/u`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly (which I might not have), then you simply want to use the `^`  and `$` characters to specify that "the match HAS to start here and the match HAS to end here":

```
/^([\p{L} -]+)$/u
 ^            ^
```

Then `preg_match` would only return true if the string had nothing else in it.

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/rZ7gG6)

**Edit**:

If hyphens/spaces are only allowed in the middle:

```
/^([\p{L}](?:[\p{L} -]+[\p{L}])?)$/u
```

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/gV6xZ0)

Comment: Oops i'm gone too quickly. If a genius completes the field with an hyphen it returns true. Or this is not which is expected.

Comment: @Plumy So hyphens are allowed, just not as the first/last character?

Comment: Yes, I think it's a good summary. I didn't saw it like this but that's it !

Comment: Ok. Now It's all good ! :)

I guess if I want the string is in uppercase I just need to replace p{L} by p{Lu} ?

Comment: @Plumy According to [the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) that'd definitely be the way to go. :)